# How to execute Sql query from batch file

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I'm new to batch files scripting.

All I want is creating a batch file that is calling SQL file and store results in CSV file .

Can anyone help me, your help is highly appreciated.

I am using Oracle database (version : oracle 11g)

Update:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<host>)(PORT=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=whipripa)));
uid=<uid>;pwd=<pswd>;"
```

While executing above query, it's not giving any errors, but still it's not connecting to Database either. Can someone tell me how to go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a template of SQL Plus Script:

```
set colsep ,
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 2
set numwidth 5

spool books.csv

SELECT
  title,
  primary_author
FROM
  books;

spool off
```

you’ll simply issue the sqlplus command from your shell:

```
sqlplus user/pwd@mydb @query.sql
```

Comment: @Shivangi - That's not helpful information. Gather up the exact code you ran, the exact error messages you got, etc, etc, and put them in your Question.